# CURL returns nothing only on certain sites on a certain host

Tags: php, curl

I have been using curl to get an xml response from a payment gateway since last january and before another one using the same code since about 5 years. Last friday it stopped working and the code hasn't been modified and  both the host and the payment gateway tell me nothing has changed either.

I have done multiple tests to access the url with curl, fopen and file_get_contents to try to make it work. I seem to be able to access common sites like Google, Facebook and php.net but not the site I want and other sites i worked on.

The code I use for testing is :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // comment once in production
if(!curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url)) {echo 'CURLOPT URL Error<p>';}
if(!curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1)) {echo 'CURLOPT Header Error<p>';}
if(!curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('POST /AUTHORIZE HTTP/1.0', 'MIME-Version: 1.0', 'Content-type: application/PTI21',
'Content-transfer-encoding: text', 'Request-number: 1', 'Document-type: Request'))) {echo 'CURLOPT HTTPHEADER Error<p>';}
if(!curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90)) {echo 'CURLOPT TIMEOUT Error<p>';} 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // gives error, but keeps xml formatting

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
$options = array(
    'return_info'   => true,
    'method'        => 'post'
);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($result);


$fd = fopen( $url, "r" );
if( !$fd )
{
    echo "Cannot open URL";
} else {
    while ( !feof( $fd ) ) {
        $buffer = fgets( $fd, 4096 );
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose ( $fd );
}
```

I was wondering if there was anything wrong with it because on another host it works everytime and with the host it's on, it only works for half the sites i try.

Comment: try `curl_error` and `curl_info` to check if u get any error.

Comment: You should check if the access control on the payment gateway side has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a valid response without knowing the actual URL.

One problem could be that the URL is redirecting, for example when some people redirect domain.com to www.domain.com.

For those scenarios you can use.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Please run the command below to get some more information on what happened.

```
print_r(curl_info($ch));
```

Put that code right below the curl_exec

Comment: curl_getinfo return
    Array ( [url] => https://orbital1.paymentech.net/authorize [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 ) 
and curl_error before the exec returned nothing and after couldn't connect to host

Comment: Did you run the curl_info AFTER the curl_exec?